# group_concat() on multiple columns on multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to query 2 tables from the db and want to have just one row as a result using group_concat().
But with the query I have created I get the db entrys not just once but multiple times and I don't know why:

My query: [Link to db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=jIp0TUSh0M)

```
SELECT a.owner,
       group_concat(causConc, '') AS attributes,
       group_concat(causConc2, '') AS reqs
FROM (SELECT a.owner,
             '{' || key || ',' || group_concat(value, ',') || ';' || '}' AS causConc
      FROM attributes a
      WHERE a.owner = 162012
      GROUP BY a.owner,
               key) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT owner,
             '{' || key || ',' || group_concat(value, ',') || ';' || '}' AS causConc2
      FROM reqs r
      WHERE r.owner = 162012
      GROUP BY r.owner,
               key) r 
ON a.owner = r.owner
GROUP BY a.owner
```

Can anyone please tell me why I get those db entrys multiple times?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join computes all possible combinations of matching rows from the two sources.

To just concatenate rows from two sources, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT owner,
       group_concat(causConc, '') AS attributes,
       group_concat(causConc2, '') AS reqs
FROM (SELECT owner, causConc, NULL AS causConc2
      FROM (... first subquery ...)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT owner, NULL, causConc2
      FROM (... second subquery ...))
GROUP BY owner;
```